# Firefox extension. DOMContentLoaded fires more than once on some pages

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, addeventlistener, xul

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // stuff that happens for each web page load goes here
}, false),false)
```

I am having the following problem with this code: `DOMContentLoaded` fires more than once on some pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DOMContentLoaded will be called for iframes as well. If you want to ignore these calls, you can do something like this:

```
function onLoaded(event) {
  var isFrame = (event.target instanceof Ci.nsIDOMHTMLDocument &&
    event.target != browser.contentDocument);
  if (isFrame) {
    return;
  }
}
```